# "handshake_failure" on some HTTPS urls

Tags: https, netty, sslhandshakeexception

I have tried the snoop example, i.e. HttpSnoopClient, with some HTTPS example urls and I get "handshake_failure".
For example with "https://www.topixstars.com/quiz/18926/qidx40" or "https://moviebay.io/watch/live-pd-season-2-episode-20-12-9-17" I get the following exception :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:292)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1256)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1159)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1202)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
```

I can visit these pages with Chrome and Firefox browsers and
according to "https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html" these domains seems have correct certificates.

I have executed HttpSnoopClient program with "-Djavax.net.debug=all" VM argument on "https://moviebay.io/watch/live-pd-season-2-episode-20-12-9-17" url and I see :

```
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing         javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

complete logs are here : https://ufile.io/s9xtf

With openssl command :

```
openssl s_client -connect moviebay.io:443
```

I get :

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140053994227352:error:14077410:SSL     routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake     failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

No ALPN negotiated
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1
        Cipher    : 0000
        Session-ID: 
        Session-ID-ctx: 
        Master-Key: 
        Key-Arg   : None
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        Start Time: 1518084692
        Timeout   : 300 (sec)
        Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    ---

Someone can explains me what is going wrong?

Best Regards.

Comment: I have executed HttpSnoopClient program with "-Djavax.net.debug=all" VM argument on "https://moviebay.io/watch/live-pd-season-2-episode-20-12-9-17" url and I see :

    nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
    nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
    nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing         javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure